# Loading React Component From button click on Extjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs, react-router, navigation

I am currently working on integrating react project with existing extjs project.The requirement is to load a react component in an extjs page when a button is clicked, button resides in ext project

Answer (score 1):

It is not so easy but you can begin from the following small code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Hello',
    width: 200,
    height: 300,
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            text: "Load React Component",
            handler: function () {
                const panel = this.up('panel');
                const e = React.createElement;
                ReactDOM.render(
                    e('div', null, 'React'),
                    panel.body.el.dom
                );
            }
        }]
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

and index.html

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <!-- for Production -->
    <!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>-->
    <!--<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>-->
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36q5)

Or you create a div with some ID in extjs panel's body using template or htmn property of panel and render your react project there.

P.S.
it is very bad idea to integrate extjs with react.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I am looking for pointers on the second approach you've mentioned.

Comment: I have changed the fiddle. Have a look again please.

Comment: Can we use something alternative to ReactDOM.render ? and do something to make ext render minified js and css files from actual react build(having components).
Thinking in terms of real world scenario.

Comment: ExtJs can render application into a div using 'renderTo' property or render method. React can reander app into div using ReactDOM.render method. Theoretically it must work.
So you are creating a div with some id in extjs and rendering into this div your react app, or you create a div with id and rendering extjs app into that div.
Anyway it is very bad practice mix them. You will have two separate build processing for react and extjs.. I would avoid to do it.